# How do Swift's heterogenous value type arrays work?

Tags: swift, interface, value-type

I'm a C++ programmer just starting out with Swift. I watched Dave Abrahams' WWCD talk ["Protocol Orientated Programming in Swift"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/) and I was intrigued by the way that it's possible to create a heterogeneous array of value types constrained by a protocol.

To use the example from the video, given a protocol `Drawable` and two structs which implement it:

```
protocol Drawable {
    func draw(renderer: Renderer) // Renderer is another protocol
}

struct Circle : Drawable {
    func draw(renderer: Renderer) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

struct Rectangle : Drawable {
    func draw(renderer: Renderer) {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

It's possible to define a `Diagram` as containing an array of `Drawable`s

```
struct Diagram : Drawable {
    var elements: [Drawable] = []

    func draw(renderer: Renderer) {
        for e in elements {
            e.draw(renderer);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how exactly does this heterogenous `elements` array work under the covers? As the various implementations of `Drawable` can vary in size, I can't see how they can be laid out in an efficient array in memory. Does this mean that such a "protocol array" is actually using per-element heap allocation and dynamic/virtual function calls under the surface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious about the same, although I did not have time enough to completely get to the bottom of it.  Still I think I have gotten some approximation worth of placing here as an answer.

Firstly, there it this [article](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/thinking-swift-part-ii/) from Jason Bell, which provides some hints at how it all works behind the scenes (not only for Swift but also for Objective-C and other languages).

Secondly, if I take this simple program:

```
protocol Foo { }

struct Bar: Foo { }

var fooArray = [Foo]()

fooArray.append(Bar())
fooArray.append(Bar())
fooArray.append(Bar())

let arrayElement = fooArray[0]

print(arrayElement)
```

... and compile it into `LLVM IR` by doing `swiftc -emit-ir unveil.swift > unveil.ir` then I can fish out the following `IR` code that corresponds to a simple `fooArray.append(Bar())`:

```
%15 = getelementptr inbounds %P6unveil3Foo_* %3, i32 0, i32 1
store %swift.type* bitcast (i64* getelementptr inbounds ({ i8**, i64, { i64, i8*, i32, i32, i8*, %swift.type** (%swift.type*)*, %swift.type_pattern*, i32, i32, i32 }*, %swift.type* }* @_TMfV6unveil3Bar, i32 0, i32 1) to %swift.type*), %swift.type** %15, align 8
%16 = getelementptr inbounds %P6unveil3Foo_* %3, i32 0, i32 2
store i8** getelementptr inbounds ([0 x i8*]* @_TWPV6unveil3BarS_3FooS_, i32 0, i32 0), i8*** %16, align 8
%17 = getelementptr inbounds %P6unveil3Foo_* %3, i32 0, i32 0
call void @_TFV6unveil3BarCfMS0_FT_S0_()
%18 = bitcast %P6unveil3Foo_* %3 to %swift.opaque*
call void @_TFSa6appendurfRGSaq__Fq_T_(%swift.opaque* noalias nocapture %18, %swift.type* %14, %Sa* nocapture dereferenceable(8) @_Tv6unveil8fooArrayGSaPS_3Foo__)
```

[Here](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) you can find the LLVM IR syntax, but for me above means that Swift arrays are really arrays of pointers.

Also, similarly to `IR`, I can get to the assembly for the same Swift line, which is:

```
leaq    __TWPV6unveil3BarS_3FooS_(%rip), %rax
leaq    __TMfV6unveil3Bar(%rip), %rcx
addq    $8, %rcx
movq    %rcx, -56(%rbp)
movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
callq   __TFV6unveil3BarCfMS0_FT_S0_
leaq    __Tv6unveil8fooArrayGSaPS_3Foo__(%rip), %rdx
leaq    -80(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
movq    -160(%rbp), %rsi
callq   __TFSa6appendurfRGSaq__Fq_T_
```

... again, above manipulates the pointers, so that confirms the theory.

And finally, there are SIL headers `SILWitnessTable.h` and `SILWitnessVisitor.h` from [swift.org](https://github.com/apple/swift/) to be found at `swift/include/swift/SIL/` that suggest the same.

Actually, I *guess* (and I hope that someone who really knows what he's talking about would weigh in here) that value-types (e.g. `struct`s) and reference-types (read `class`es) are not so much different under the hood of Swift.  Probably the main difference is whether copy-on-write in enforced or not.

Comment: Fantastic work, although the assembly is a little over my head I agree with your conclusions. If "value types" are really always heap-allocated, and if arrays always just store pointers then that would seem a little disappointing from a performance point of view, but maybe that's just my C++ bias showing!

Comment: I might be all wrong.  It's a deep forest to go through, actually.  And the shape of the program changes quite dramatically all the way Swift->AST->raw SIL->canonical SIL->LLVM IR->assembly.  They do a lot of smart stuff in there on each layer, so I would not be too worried about performance.  BTW, another great read is: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/10/os-x-10-10/22/